# Can't figure out how to fix these docker mysql container errors [ sequence number 29689014 is in the future! ]

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose, path

this is from docker-compose up:

mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20 19:15:16+02:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20 19:15:16+02:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.27-1debian10 started.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.757806Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 1
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.776900Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.929728Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_002' Page [page id: space=4294967278, page number=4] log sequence number 29689014 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.932212Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935598Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=5] log sequence number 29689251 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935648Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935721Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=283] log sequence number 29689251 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935745Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935787Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=4] log sequence number 29688761 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935807Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935868Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=514] log sequence number 29688761 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.935885Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.936122Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_002' Page [page id: space=4294967278, page number=259] log sequence number 29689014 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 29664236.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:16.936157Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:17.005605Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:17.015218Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:17.015510Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:17.015897Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql_3sem | 2021-10-20T17:15:17.545475Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_3sem exited with code 1

Comment: That YAML fragment looks correct.  Can you edit the question to include a more complete `docker-compose.yml` file (just including the database container is fine) and the output from the container when you run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Yeah no problem